# Power distribution problem in multi-camera usb array

Tags: voltage, current, usb, usb-device, usb-hub

**Problem Summary**

My MacBook Pro (development system) can successfully capture images from 24 cameras in the multi camera assembly we have assembled. But when our assembly is attached to a new Raspberry Pi 400 (target deployment system), Linux only mounts up to 18  of the 24 available cameras.

The RPi system log sometimes shows:

**“USB Device over current status detected”**

at boot up time if the assembly is already connected,  or at attachment time if the USB cable is connected after boot up.

I suspect that this problem may be a power related problem, but I don't know how to diagnose this problem, nor which steps I must take to repair the problem.

In trial and error Attempts to access more of the cameras on the Pi, I have tested configurations in which additional power input is provided to the hubs.  But these trials have not succeeded.

**Details and Research**

Our multi-camera array is made of 24 or 18 USB cameras and 4 to 5 USB 7-port hubs, that are attached to a controlling computer (Mac or RPi400) via a single USB cable.

The hubs can be optionally powered using USB-c cables.

I have attached this assembly to both my MacBook Pro (development system), and to a Raspberry Pi 400 (target deployment system). While all 24 cameras are accessible when connected to the Mac, The RPI will only detect up to 18 cameras, and sometimes it won't even find that many.

USB Camera array configurations:
Note that all cameras, hubs, cables and the USB port on the computers are all rated  USB3.

[image: 24 camera spoke configuration]
[image: 24 camera daisy chain configuration]
[image: 18 camera spoke configuration]
[image: 18 camera daisy chain configuration]

**What I’ve tried:**

I have tried connecting external power to zero up to all of the hubs.  I have tried them arranged in both spoke and daisy chain configurations shown for both 24 and 18 cameras.

I can put USB amp-voltmeters between any 2 USB devices, as well as on the power inputs to the hubs when they are receiving external power.

With external power to all hubs, the meter between the master hub and the computer reads a steady 5.15V and 0amps.

I am guessing that the difference between the Mac and the RPi response may have something to do with how much voltage or amperage the RPi USB port can handle, and that those values are different for the MacBook Pro.

I have uploaded a diagram of the 18 Camera Spoke Configuration with the measured voltage and amperage on each USB data line, and each power in line for each hub.

I used a USB voltage/amperage tester with a single camera, and it shows an initial voltage of 5.16V that drops to 5.12V immediately after connection, and then returns to a 5.16V steady state.

The LED string is reading 4.5V and 2mA steady.
[image: 18 Camera spoke config showing Voltage and Amperage on each data line and power line]

What suggestions can you offer as to what Voltage and Amperage measurements should be measured, and where to measure them to determine what is causing the hardware errors.

Comment: I don't know whether that is the case, but some USB host controller hardware is just buggy, and starts failing with many attached devices. Also, I do know that camera drivers in the Linux kernel are of especially inhomogenous quality, and, at least for cheap webcams, there have been multiple bugs related to having > 1 of the same camera. Did you test your setup on your development machine when booting Linux on it, or was this done solely under OS X?

Comment: With that many hubs and cameras connected, there could be no "optional power adapters". The external power is a MUST, not "optional". For ALL hubs. What is the power consumption for each camera? Even then, 1.2A for "optional" power supply might be not enough to keep power for the hub electronics (~1W) and six (!!!) cams. Do you math please.

Comment: Marcus Müller, I did the development on OS X only.  I have run multiple cameras on the RPi before, and indeed I am regularly detecting 18 of the 24 connected.  I do recognize that Linux uses TWO dev numbers for each of these cameras, but even that should only consume at most 48 slots in a table.  Add 5 more for the hubs and 4 internal ports and it is still only using 57 slots of a table that should be able to have 127 addressable slots.  Now it is possible that there is a bug in the Video4Linux2 drivers or in the Raspbian kernel, which is why I am asking  for help here.

Comment: Ale.chenski: I used a USB voltage/amperage tester with a single camera, and  it shows an initial voltage of 5.16V that drops to 5.12V immediately after connection, and then returns to a 5.16V steady state.  The Amperage climbs from 0.00A to 0.03A before settling back to 0.00A.   The pulse at connection time lasts about 2 seconds.

Comment: If we have 24 cameras on the USB bus in serial (daisy chained hubs), would that mean that amperage spike would be 24*0.03A = .72A for all 24? with a Voltage drop spike of .04V *24=.96V?

Comment: Ale..chenski: I used a USB multi-meter on a single camera, and it reports a voltage of 5.16, and an amperage of .01A.   I am uploading a new diagram to the original post, showing Voltage and Amperage on each data line  and power in line shown.

Comment: Cheaper 5V powered hubs typically have a simple diode that connects the host USB power to the external wall wart power.  When the external power is connected, the diode is reverse biased, which is why you measure no current between the PI and the hub.  If the overcurrent warning isn't just a software glitch, you could try desoldering/cutting the diode out, which will completely disconnect the host and device power supplies.

Comment: I am afraid that your "USB multimeter" does not provide actual USB data connection, and therefore cannot measure the actual power consumption of the devices in actively enumerated states. These "multimeters" are good only for charging applications.

Comment: Ale..chenski: if the USB multimeters won't tell me the current and voltage consumed by the camera, LED and Hubs,  what is a way I can determine that information?

Comment: Main source of info should be in manufacturer's specifications. The second (upper) estimation can be from MaxPower field in "configuration Descriptor:, which can be easily taken woth USBTreeViewer. Accurate measurements require special equipment, and also require to engage a worst-case video pattern.

Comment: Ale..chenski,  that was helpful.  I just ran lsusb and captured the Max Power for all cameras, and the LED.  The LED is powered by a USB 5V port, but is not a registered USB Device, so I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Ale..chenksi: Each of the 18 cameras responding reports "MaxPower 500mA". 
Each slave hub reports "MaxPower 0mA". 
The root hub reports  "MaxPower 100mA". 
18*500mA = 9.0A + 5*0mA + 100A = 9.1A.  

The RPi USB3.0 type A port is rated to support a .9A minimum. 
The MBP usb-c USB3.1 port is rated to support a minimum of 3A.  and does detect all 24 cameras even without any external power to the hubs, while the RPi is only seeing 18.  If the cameras actually drew 500mA each, I would expect that even two of them would max out the USB3.0 bus and that's not the case.

Comment: Ale..chenski: So, if "Accurate measurements require special equipment", what equipment would be needed to determine the actual amperage?

Comment: Cameras don't "actually draw" max power, it is likely that they can do it under some very special image pattern at highest possible frame rate (which does not happen on a simple USB enumeration process). Likely they draw 100-200 mA. To measure power consumption during actual operation of your devices, you will need something like this, https://teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/usb/voyager-m310p. Or at least https://www.passmark.com/products/usb-power-delivery-tester/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I am familiar with usb-power-delivery-testers, but I was not aware that this digital protocol analyzer tracks analog voltage (at the physical layer).  I've previously only used digital protocol analyzers to inspect digital features at the network (packet) or transport (datagram) levels.  Thanks for alerting me.